# Is it a good pattern to use an Object as an indexed array in JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, coding-style, ecmascript-6

I have seen this pattern many times:

```
var messages = {};

function addMessage(newMessage) {
  messages[newMessage.id] = newMessage;
}

function numUnread() {
  var unread = 0;
  for (var id in messages) {
    if (messages[id]) {
      unread++;
    }
  }
  return unread;
}
```

One problem of using JavaScript objects as if they where associative arrays is that it is not possible to use convenient array methods like `length`, `filter`, `map`, etc.

So, would it be better to use an array instead?

```
let messages = [];

function addMessage(newMessage) {
  const newMessages = messages
      .filter(msg => msg.id !== newMessage.id)
      .push(newMessage);
  messages = newMessages;
}

function numUnread() {
  return messages.filter(msg => !msg.isRead).length();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing really wrong with using objects, you just have to ensure that your keys don't collide with `Object.prototype` methods. Which is pretty easy if they're numeric ids.

However, in ES6, you should just use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). This also allows you to easily get the size. Unfortunately, it has not array-like helper methods (yet), but it does work well with iterators.

```
const messages = new Map();

function addMessage(newMessage) {
  messages.set(newMessage.id, newMessage);
}

function numUnread() {
  let unread = 0;
  for (let {isRead} of messages.values())
    if (!isRead)
      unread++;
  return unread;
}
```